# Name of "a period of time worked offshore" (usually 21 days)

Tags: single-word-requests

I thought of shift but it didn't sound right given it's a longer period of time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One phrase in use in the oil industry is ***tour*** or more fully ***tour of duty***, by extension from the military or diplomatic service.

[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tour?q=tour+of+duty#tour__11) lists the latter users.

Comment: Stint is also used "a period of time spent at a particular activity" http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stint